# L1-regularization to all weights (not weights and bias) in neural network in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using TensorFlow's eager execution.

For L1-regularization I am using `tf.contrib.layers.l1_regularizer`. I do not know how I can apply the regularizer just to the weights. `tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(l1_regularizer, model.trainable_weights)` also apply the regularization to the bias because `model.trainable_weights` also returns bias. But I do not know how to just get the weights from the model.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()

#create loss function with regularizer
def loss(model, x, y, l1_regularizer):
   y_ = model(x)
   weights = model.trainable_weights
   return tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=y_)+tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(l1_regularizer, weights)

 #function for gradient calculation
  def grad(model, inputs, targets, l1_regularizer):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets, l1_regularizer)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables)


  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.5)
  global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()

  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid, input_shape=(2,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid)
  ])    

 #set weights
  weights=[np.array([[0.15, 0.25],[0.2,0.3]]),np.array([0.35,0.35]),np.array([[0.4,0.5],[0.45, 0.55]]),np.array([0.6,0.6])]

model.set_weights(weights)

model.get_weights()

 features = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.05,0.10 ]])
 labels =  tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.01,0.99 ]])  


 model(features) 
 #calculate the loss
 loss(model, features, labels,l1_regularizer)
  #calculate the gradients
 loss, grads = grad(model, features, labels,l1_regularizer)
 #optimization step
 optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),
                                      global_step)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Keras layers, the weights usually will have 'kernel' in their name. Use this to subset out the weights from all the trainables.

```
weights = [x for x in model.trainable_weights if 'kernel' in x.name]
tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(l1_regularizer, weights)
```

Make sure you use the right case for the name, if it's 'Kernel' instead of 'kernel' it won't work.

If you don't want to apply L1 to specifically biases

```
weights = [x for x in model.trainable_weights if 'bias' not in x.name]
tf.contrib.layers.apply_regularization(l1_regularizer, weights)
```

---

Alternatively, Keras layers also have an option of adding a regularizer for weights, bias or activation. From the documentation for [Dense](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense):

> **kernel_regularizer**: Regularizer function applied to the kernel weights matrix.
>
> **bias_regularizer**: Regularizer function applied to the bias vector.
>
> **activity_regularizer**: Regularizer function applied to the output of the layer (its "activation")..

So you need to import the regularizers from keras and add them as an option to your layers.

```
from tf.keras import regularizers
    ....
    ....

 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid, input_shape=(2,), kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1()),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1())
  ])
```

Comment: if I use `weights = [x for x in model.trainable_weights if 'bias' not in x.name]` everything works fine. But if I use the `kernel_regularizer` the regularization is applied twice. Here the problem is described in more detail [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52874156/how-to-apply-l1-regularization-to-the-weights-not-to-bias-in-all-layers-in-a-n)